# How can I change coding style for C/C++ in Monodevelop 2.8?

Tags: styles, monodevelop

These languages are supported by MonoDevelop, and there is a way to change the coding style for C#, but how can I do the same for C and C++?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I contacted a MonoDevelop devoloper, who indicated that this functionality does not exist in MonoDevelop.